# Google VM - Potentially erroneous full disk size report

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, conda, diskspace

I was trying to install a docker image on Google VM.
One of the operations on the dockerfile, was building a conda environment.

Here is the particular command: `RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml`.

However, during the execution of this command, i started to receive errors that the disk space is full.

Here is one of these particular messages: `[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/opt/conda/pkgs/libxkbcommon-1.0.3-he3ba5ed_0.tar.bz2'`

I exited the operation and i run a disk check with `df -h`.

Here are the results of the command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  5.3M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  6.0G  3.2G  66% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

It does not seem that the disk space is full. So what is going on here? And why i cannot proceed with my operation?

EDIT:
Like i said in a comment, the docker image in my system, natively, eats up 3.3GB. So i am really close.

The image is 10gb, so i want to increase it a bit further.

[image]

However, there is no option to increase its size in the editor:
[image]

And when i click on the 'Create Disks' icon here:
[image]

I think i can only create a new disk.
[image]

Where is the option to resize this one?

EDIT 2/2:
I stopped the instance but there is no edit button in Disks
[image]

Comment: I guess that the `conda env create` step takes more than 3.2 GB, so Docker cannot build the layer associated with this step. Because it can't, when you exit your Docker build, the layer has not been created so it is not persisted on your disk (that's why you don't see it with `df`). To check if my assumption is correct, could you try to 1) increase the disk space of your VM or 2) build the image locally and check the remaining disk space before and after ?

Comment: I checked and the particular docker image locally - eats up 3.3GB.

Comment: Ok, so if you want to build this image on a Compute Engine VM, as you may have concluded by yourself, I suggest you to increase the disk size.

Comment: @norbjd Thank you. I am having trouble resizing this disk. I updated the question. Could you please take a look at it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Shut down the instance. Go Compute Engine -> Disks. Select your disk and click the EDIT button. Then you will be able to resize.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you! I stopped the instance, went to disks but i couldn't edit my disk. I have updated my question with a picture.

Comment: Click on the disk name which takes you to the disk details page. Then there is an edit button.